# How to decide on which part to use honorifics?

Tags: grammar, honorific

I have seen that sometimes the honorific is used for only some part of the sentence, such as at the subject particle or verb. For example,

> 할머니가 식용유를 사려고 슈퍼마켓에 가셨어요.

In this sentence, the honorific is not used at the subject particle (께서). In other cases, honorifics are not used at all.

So I wonder how to decide if I use the honorifics and on which part to use?

Comment: Using 께서 is fine in this sentence, I think. Also it's 슈퍼마켓. It's very hard question, though.

Comment: Not 사려고 가셨어요 but 사러 가셨어요 is correct.

Answer (score 5):

There are the three factors for Korean honorific speech: (a) **subject honorification**, (b) object exaltation, and (c) speech styles. (You may refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorifics_(linguistics)#Korean).)

Your question and example relate to the first one. These words belong to it:

1. -(으)시- (meaning "-으시- or -시-")
2. -께서
3. others used for honorific speech (-님, -분, 계시다, 잡수다, 주무시다, 아드님, 따님, 진지, 말씀, 댁, 생신, 춘추, ...)

> 할머니가 식용유를 사러 슈퍼마켓에 가**셨**어요.

Because this includes -시- (가**시**었어요 is shortened as 가셨어요), the sentence shows the subject honorification although it does not have -께서.

> 할머니**께서** 식용유를 사러 슈퍼마켓에 가**셨**어요.

This follows a reference, [표준 언어 예절(2011) - 경어법](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/reportData/reportDataView.do?mn_id=207&report_seq=767). It sounds better to me.

> 할머니**께서** 식용유를 사**시**러 슈퍼마켓에 가**셨**어요.

This sounds a bit awkward to me (because 가다 is the last verb and I usually use -(으)시- for the last verb/adjective only); it is also correct but not advisable according to the reference.

I have heard all the three kinds of sentences. People tend *not* to use -께서 for casual conversation. When you have to follow the guidelines (for example, in formal situations), however, you should use -께서.

---

The [national institute](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=124174) mentions why 께서 is *not often* used in *speaking Korean* as the following:

> 존칭의 조사 '께서', '께'는 대화에서는 잘 쓰이지 않는다. 용언의 '-시-'로도 충분히 높였다고 생각하기 때문이다.

That is, people think using -(으)시- is sufficient for the subject honorification in speaking Korean.